# What is the difference between writing CSS on one class and writing the same in combination with another class?

Tags: css

What difference will it make to my CSS class when I am writing it twice, once with just the class name and once in combination with another class name

```
.User_Profile{
    padding : 10px;
    margin  : 16px;
    background-image : url("images/user.png");
    font-size: 20px;
             }

.User_Profile, .Premium{
    font-family: cursive;
    display: block
    background-image : url("images/P_user.png");
    font-size: 20px;

                       }
```

How will the browser process an HTML element when I've used an element with class="User_Profile" and once with class="User_Profile Premium"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As those booth classes have the same [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity), the later one in the source file will take precedence and override those properties. However, if you change the rule to `.User_Profile.Premium` it would only apply for the `<element class="User_Profile Premium">` but the rule you have written apply to both `<element class="User_Profile">` and `<element class="Premium">`.

Comment: so what good will it make by writhing .selector_1 , .selector_2{/* css */}

Comment: where can we use such statements

Comment: If you want to style two or more different classes or elements use a comma (`,`) to separate them and the rules will apply to all those selectors. Please see [What Is the Comma for in CSS Selectors?](https://www.thoughtco.com/comma-in-css-selectors-3467052)

Answer (score 0):

a div with class `User_Profile Premium` will override all properties of the `User_Profile` selector.

```
.User_Profile {
    padding : 10px;
    margin  : 16px;
    background-image : url("images/user.png"); // <-- overvritten
    font-size: 20px;                           // <-- overvritten
}

.User_Profile, .Premium {
    font-family: cursive;
    display: block
    background-image : url("images/P_user.png");
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

In your case are this the properties `background-image` and `font-size`. To prevent this you could use this code:

```
.User_Profile, .Not_Premium {
    padding : 10px;
    margin  : 16px;
    background-image : url("images/user.png");
    font-size: 20px;
}

.User_Profile, .Premium {
    padding : 10px;
    margin  : 16px;
    font-family: cursive;
    display: block
    background-image : url("images/P_user.png");
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

Note when you're using CSS transpilers, you could extend `.Premium` selector from `.User_Profile`.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways you can write multiple CSS selectors in a declaration.

When you separate two selectors by a comma, you're telling the browser to apply the CSS rules to all of those selectors. It's the same as writing each selector separately with its own declaration block.

**Example:**

```
// This is the same
.User_Profile, .Premium {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: red;
}

// As this:
.User_Profile {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: red;
}

.Premium {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: red;
}
```

If you remove the comma, the CSS rule will apply to a child element of the first selector.

**Example:**

```css
.User_Profile .Premium {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="User_Profile">
    <div class="Premium">Applied</div>
</div>

<div class="Premium">Not Applied</div>
```

If you want the CSS rule to only apply to an element that uses *both* classes, you remove the space between the two selectors.

**Example:**

```css
.User_Profile.Premium {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="User_Profile Premium">
    This div has the rule applied.
</div>

<div class="User_Profile">
    This div does not have the rule applied.
</div>

<div class="Premium">
    This div does not have the rule applied.
</div>
```

You can also do more advanced techniques, like selecting only direct descendants by placing a **>** symbol between selectors.